# Spark Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources

Tags: java, apache-spark, cluster-computing

I am having an issue while trying to use a Spark Cluster ( Spark 3.3 , Hadoop 3.2.4 ) running a Standalone Manager. First, I started Spark Cluster, both Master and 3 Workers and I checked Spark UI page where I can see them up and running. My client Driver code is being executed from my local environment from IntelliJ. After an initial setup :

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("CSSparkSQL").setMaster(master)
            .set("spark.executor.memory", execMem)
            .set("spark.driver.memory", driverMem)
            .set("spark.driver.maxResultSize", maxResultSize)
            .set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", "true")
            .set("spark.memory.offHeap.enabled", String.valueOf(!offHeap.startsWith("0")) )
            .set("spark.memory.offHeap.size", offHeap)
            .set("spark.executor.cores", maxCores)
            .set("spark.cores.max", maxCores)
            .set("spark.sql.debug.maxToStringFields", "5000")
            .set("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", "5000")
            .set("spark.executor.instances", "100")
            .set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
            .set("spark.sql.windowsExec.buffer.spill.threshold", "15000")
            .set("spark.shuffle.service.enabled", "false")
            .set("spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled", "false");

    spark = SparkSession.builder().config(conf)
            .getOrCreate();
```

I am making a call to read the data to the DataSet from the local file :

Dataset existingDS = spark.read().csv("C:\Files\testData\data_2.txt");

and I am getting this message in the Console :

```
Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources
```

I am running my application in the Debug mode and after I step into the above mentioned code I went to the Spark UI and I saw that my application actually connected to the Spark Cluster. I drill down to the Executor-Worker page and check "stdout" logs. I see an exception there :

```
19:14:19 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to <myMachineName>/<myIpAddress> after 156 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
19:14:21 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from <myMachineName>/<myIpAddress>

java.io.InvalidClassException: 
scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef; local class 
    incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = 
1028182004549731694, local class 
    serialVersionUID = 3456489343829468865
```

Scala dependency in my project :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.15</version>
        </dependency>
```

Spark Cluster libraries under "SPARK_HOME/jars/"

```
jackson-module-scala_2.12-2.13.3.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   348265 Jun  9 20:37 json4s-scalap_2.12-3.7.0-M11.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   112235 Jun  9 20:37 scala-collection-compat_2.12-2.1.1.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp 10978529 Jun  9 20:37 scala-compiler-2.12.15.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp  5443542 Jun  9 20:37 scala-library-2.12.15.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   222980 Jun  9 20:37 scala-parser-combinators_2.12-1.1.2.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp  3678167 Jun  9 20:37 scala-reflect-2.12.15.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   556575 Jun  9 20:37 scala-xml_2.12-1.2.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp 12537344 Jun  9 20:37 spark-catalyst_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp 10997851 Jun  9 20:37 spark-core_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   434006 Jun  9 20:37 spark-graphx_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   711266 Jun  9 20:37 spark-hive_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   566338 Jun  9 20:37 spark-hive-thriftserver_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   524869 Jun  9 20:37 spark-kubernetes_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    83989 Jun  9 20:37 spark-kvstore_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    77705 Jun  9 20:37 spark-launcher_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   298786 Jun  9 20:37 spark-mesos_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp  6138879 Jun  9 20:37 spark-mllib_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   116144 Jun  9 20:37 spark-mllib-local_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp  2414964 Jun  9 20:37 spark-network-common_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   160299 Jun  9 20:37 spark-network-shuffle_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    51685 Jun  9 20:37 spark-repl_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    30727 Jun  9 20:37 spark-sketch_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp  8858938 Jun  9 20:37 spark-sql_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp  1138844 Jun  9 20:37 spark-streaming_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    15151 Jun  9 20:37 spark-tags_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    10807 Jun  9 20:37 spark-tags_2.12-3.3.0-tests.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp    53194 Jun  9 20:37 spark-unsafe_2.12-3.3.0.jar
-rw-------  1 e2efcstd 70622_e2e_unix_dev_busp   357528 Jun  9 20:37 spark-yarn_2.12-3.3.0.jar
```

Comment: Which version of scala and spark are you using, it seems that the scala version is not compatible with your spark version.

Comment: I am not using Scala at all, I am using Java 8, Spark version is 3.3

Answer (score 0):

Please verify that both the Spark version and the Scala version of your driver matches the versions of your cluster. The `InvalidClassException` you are seeing in your logs is a known [Scala bug](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/5046) and got fixed in Scala 2.12.14.

The issue happens when using a driver with Scala 2.12.[10..13] and a Spark cluster that uses Scala >= 2.12.14 or vise versa. Spark 3.2.2 and later are using Scala 2.12.15.

Note: Even when using the Java API of Spark, Scala will be pulled as a transitive dependency of Spark. Have a look at your dependency graph in IntelliJ to check the version of Scala that get's included.

Comment: You're correct, I have Scala 2.12.8 in my dependencies in Driver application. Updating to 2.12.16, let's see what happens

Comment: It didn't work , I can see the same error

Comment: Unless it's a much older Spark version, you shouldn't see Scala 2.12.8 on your classpath. Could you update the question to include your pom / dependencies, pls. Also, what image are you running your Spark cluster on?

Comment: I am not running Spark in a Container, just starting Master/Workers on several VMs

Comment: Please add all dependencies to your question, it's impossible to know the final, resolved classpath otherwise. For Spark itself, please add the output of `ls -la $SPARK_HOME/jars | grep -E 'scala|spark'` and make sure it's the same for all VMs.

Comment: I added local dependency and SPARK_HOME/jars/ listing